# MVP Structure in Vaadin Spring

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, mvp

I'm setting up my first **Vaadin** application with **Vaadin 7.5.6** and the **official Vaadin Spring 1.0.0**. I want to use the **MVP** pattern but I'm asking myself how the components work together. Because I'm new to MVP i don't want to use any Addons, so i tried to set it up by myself.

So if I'm right, the LoginViewPresenter will give me the view over presenterInstance.getView(). This is already working fine, but how should i access to the presenter over the view? When i want to do a logic operation for my view i should do it in the presenter class. But how to call a presenter method from a view Buttonclicklistener?

My second question is if I have the UIScope annotation over my presenter class, when does Spring instantiate a new object from this class? I thougt as long as the UI exists. But after generating a random string in the constructor I'm printing out the content of the randomString variable (in the UI.class init() method) but there is always a new value.

Regards

LoginViewPresenter.java

```
@SpringComponent
@UIScope
public class LoginViewPresenter implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6286518141570430211L;

    @Autowired
    private LoginView view;

    public final String randomString;

    public LoginViewPresenter()
    {
        randomString = Utils.generateRandomString(8);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {

    }

    public LoginView getView()
    {
        return view;
    }

    public void setView(LoginView view)
    {
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

LoginView.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@UIScope
@SpringView(name = LoginView.NAME)
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements View
{
    public static final String NAME = "LoginView";

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event)
    {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view should'nt be aware of the presenter. It should fire events, and your presenter can listen to them.

Here is how I do it:

LoginView.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@UIScope
@SpringView(name = LoginView.NAME)
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements View {
    public static final String NAME = "LoginView";

    @Autowired
    private transient Collection<LoginViewListener> loginViewListeners;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        ...
        Button b = new Button("click me");
        b.addClickListener(e -> loginViewListeners.forEach(l -> l.eventFired()));
        addComponent(b);
        ...
        loginViewListeners.forEach(listener -> listener.viewInitialized(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event)
    {
    }

    public interface LoginViewListener {

        void viewInitialized(LoginView view);


        void eventFired();

    }

}
```

LoginViewPresenter.java

```
@SpringComponent
@UIScope
public class LoginViewPresenter implements LoginViewListener, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6286518141570430211L;

    private LoginView view;

    public final String randomString;

    public LoginViewPresenter() {
        randomString = Utils.generateRandomString(8);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

    }

    public LoginView getView() {
        return view;
    }

    public void setView(LoginView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void viewInitialized(LoginView v) {
        setView(v);
    }

    @Override
    void eventFired() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Does your randomString still have always a new value with this design?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please tell me where i can find the "ViewListener<T implements View>" class?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove it, you don't need it. It's an interface with viewInitialized in it, I use it so I don't have to add viewInitialized in each of my listeners... I edited my answer.

Comment: .. and don't inject the view in your presenter. When your view calls viewInitialized on its listeners, the presenter will set its view.

Comment: Alright, I just realized I can't use this approach, because in UI.java i got something like: 

setContent(applicationContext.getBean(LoginViewPresenter.class).getView());

At this point the view should be null in the presenter, because it's not autowired... So the viewInitialized method is never called... :(

Comment: With spring-vaadin you should use the SpringViewProvider and a Navigator: https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=3&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=III+-+Views+and+Navigation+with+Vaadin+Spring

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to explain... I know that I have to use the Navigator! My current architecture is a MainView, which contains a menu area (independent MenuView) and a content area. If the user does a first request without being logged in he gets redirected to the loginView. If he's logged in (written in the Vaadin session) he gets redirected to the MainView (the content area displays the Home view). So in the UI.init() method I'm building the MainView and I initialize the Navigator with the content area of the MainView. Now how should I initialize the Navigator for LoginView?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91571/discussion-between-shinchillahh-and-adrien-c).